# Mysql-workbench not connecting to mysql in a vagrant box over ssh

Tags: mysql, ssh, vagrant, virtual-machine, rdbms

I have tried all the available solutions in SO but this is still continuing. I am trying to connect Workbench to Mysql which is installed in a vagrant box. Both host and guest are Ubuntu 14.04. The attached are the screenshots. [image]

The error now :

[image]

[image]

The logs are as below

```
22:08:59 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: Existing SSH tunnel not found, opening new one
22:08:59 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: Opening SSH tunnel to 127.0.0.1:2222
22:08:59 [ERR][sshtunnel.py:notify_exception_error:233]: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/mysql-workbench/sshtunnel.py", line 298, in _connect_ssh
    look_for_keys=has_key, allow_agent=has_key)
  File "/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/paramiko/client.py", line 307, in connect
    look_for_keys, gss_auth, gss_kex, gss_deleg_creds, gss_host)
  File "/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/paramiko/client.py", line 519, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.

22:09:00 [ERR][     SSH tunnel]: Authentication error opening SSH tunnel: Authentication error. Please check that your username and password are correct and try again.
Details (Original exception message):
Authentication failed, please check credentials.
Please refer to logs for details
```

Comment: "please refer to logs for details" - maybe there is more information about your issue

Comment: @tuffkid added logs. Nothing much I could make of it

Comment: "Authentication failed." Can you connect with normal ssh to given ssh and port? What authentication are you using? What do the logs on the server say about the authentication failure?

Comment: have you tried connect to ssh without private key? (vagrant/vagrant)

Comment: @tuffkid with just username and password I am able to connect. the problem I think is the ssh key. But I am using the correct ssh key itself. can you please help me here?

Comment: @Jakuje  I am able to connect using normal ssh and port. I connect to `vagrant ssh` without any issues.

Comment: What is your version of mysql workbench? Older versions have some problems with ssh connections... maybe try to download the newest one

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky problem, but I have some recommendations based on my experience doing the same thing. First, ssh isn't necessary when connecting to MySQL on another host as a connection is usually made via port 3306. Second, I'd give your Vagrant machine a [static private IP address](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html) that you can use when connecting from the host machine. Third, I've only had success connecting as root (not sure why), but it looks like you're already doing that. And finally, MySQL by default only accepts connections from localhost which in your case is the Vagrant machine. Edit this line in /etc/my.cnf on the Vagrant machine...

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

...and change it to...

```
bind-address = 192.168.0.1
```

That's the IP of your host machine from the Vagrant machine. Alternatively you can change it to 0.0.0.0 or just comment the line to allow connections from anywhere. Make sure to restart MySQL after editing the file and try connecting again.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and this was driving me nuts as well. Then I realised that I had changed my SSH server to a different port.

This must the error that MySQL workbench shows when an SSH server is denying connections.

With Vagrant I suggest you ensure you can SSH to that port from the same client or workbench won't be able to use it as a jump box.